# Rails Fullcalendar: add custom params to source url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fullcalendar

I've got a Fullcalendar working in Rails.  I've also added extra fields to the events table and a modal to get user input.  When a record is saved, it automatically saves the user_id of the current user in the event table.

I would like to have the calendar display with only the current_user's events.

Right now the calendar.js.coffee file has this for getting the events data:

```
   eventSources: [{
  url: '/events',
}],
```

How can I fix it so only the current_user's event data shows up?
Do I put some code in the events controller?  Or something in the coffee code?

Should I add some selection code in the json part of the controller?

```
  class EventsController < ApplicationController
  # GET /events
  # GET /events.json
  def index
    @events = Event.scoped
    @events = Event.between(params['start'], params['end']) if  (params['start'] && params['end'])
   respond_to do |format|
  format.html # index.html.erb
  format.json { render :json => @events }
  end
end
```

The following doesn't seem to work:

```
      format.json { render :json => @events, :user_id => current_user.id }
```

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right way ;) Use a scope (I named it `for_user`, I can post the code about this scope if needed) in the Event model to retrieve the events of a particular user.

```
def index
  @events = Event.scoped
  @events = @events.between(params['start'], params['end']) if  (params['start'] && params['end'])
  @events = @events.for_user(params[:user_id]) if params[:user_id].present?
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # index.html.erb
    format.json { render :json => @events }
  end
end
```

Now you need to pass a `params[:user_id]` to the index action, which could be `current_user.id` in your case ;)

```
eventSources: [{
  url: '/events',
  data: { user_id: current_user.id }
}],
```

**WARNING: Security issue**

Doing this will let you be able to put any user_id in the URL and see the data of other users. Add a verification on the index action to ensure you can only access to the current_user's data:

```
@events = @events.for_user(params[:user_id]) if params[:user_id].present? && params[:user_id] == current_user.id
```

Comment: Thanks!  One more question.  How do I pass the param in the coffee script         `   eventSources: [{
  url: '/events',
}],`

Comment: If I type this into my browser, I get the json feed.  http://localhost:3000/events.json     What would I type in to the browser to get a particular user using the new param?

Comment: `localhost:3000/events.json?user_id=12` for the events of the user with id 12