# Fullcalendar rails: wrongly displaying events sources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fullcalendar

I've fullcalendar working in Rails with postgresql. I've a model 'Event' with which i'm trying to feed the calendar using eventSources. The problem is that when the calendar is displayed shows the events with the current date and time, not with the corresponding time and date of the events.

I've been looking at these questions, which I think is related to my problem. But I have not found how to fix it yet.

- [How to add event sources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18217957/how-to-add-event-sources)
- [Rails Fullcalendar: add custom params to source url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13883859/rails-fullcalendar-add-custom-params-to-source-url)

The code that I have so far:

Event controller

```
def index
  @events = Event.all
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # index.html.erb
    format.json { render :json => @events }
  end
end
private
  def set_event
    @event = Event.find(params[:id])
  end    
  def event_params
    params.require(:event).permit(:title, :start_time, :end_time)
  end
```

JavaScript

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({

          editable: true,
          eventLimit: true,
          eventSources: [{
              url: '/events'
          }]
});
```

I must confess I am new to Ruby, so it may be that I'm missing something basic (most likely).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this, Put is method in your event model

```
  def as_json(options = {})
    {
      :id => self.id,
      :title => self.title,
      :start => self.start_time,
      :end => self.end_time,
     }
  end
```

and modify fullCalender function's eventSource to this

```
eventSources: [{
              url: '/events.json'
          }]
```

Comment: welcome buddy, Please upvote the answer so it helps somebody else.